# 'WHERE' query issue in Ruby on Rails when the column is integer and string is passed as argument

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am facing an issue, while users randomly insert the string in the URL instead of primaryID. It is returning the response even though there is no record matching that string.

Model.where(id: "014aqe-133dff-232asd-1233") will result in the below SQL statement:

```
SELECT `hp_cases`.* FROM `hp_cases` WHERE `hp_cases`.`id` = 14
```

which is the same as Model.where(id: 14). I know the issue happens due to a string-to-integer conversion. Is there a solution other than changing the column type to string?

Comment: You can validate that the parameter being passed in only contains digits and redirect  or show an error if it does not.

Comment: Why does it matter? "Users" should be able to send anything they want in without causing problems.

Comment: @muistooshort Users are not supposed to see any random data.

Comment: Then your controller should be checking the current user (if any) is authorized to see what they're trying to see. A user (or bot) should be able to send anything at all in as the ID, they might get a 401, 402, 404, 500, ... status but they shouldn't be given something they're not allowed to see regardless of what they ask for.